# Setting formatting on multiple controls in a InfoPath form at one time

Tags: infopath, readonly, infopath-2007

I am creating a form that needs to have 30 or more fields either disabled or set to be read only. They need to be marked as such if the based on the value of a drop-down box.

This is something that I can do using conditional formating that I know, what I want to know is there a way to either add conditional formatting to multiple controls at once or a rule that I can set that will accomplish the same thing?

One requirement is that I can't use programming code to do this. I realize it would probably be far easier to do that way but that is a requirement given to me by my manager.

**EDIT:** Forgot to add this there are fields that still need to be edited when the other fields are read only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put it all in a section but your only option for sections is hide/show (not disable or read only). Otherwise you have to setup all the fields against that one dropdown. Huge pain but at least you only have to do it once.

An alternative, which is just about as much work, is to setup two views. One that is readonly and one that is normal. When the user changes the dropdown just flip the view. This method has a bunch of display nuances but does work.

Comment: From all the looking I have done so far, the first method seems to be the only viable option. I was hoping that there would be an easier way.

Answer (score 5):

One feature in InfoPath 2010 (can't remember if it was in 2007) that reduces the pain of this sort of repetitive work is the ability to copy-and-paste rules. With this you can create your read-only rule once and then just paste it onto each of the 30 controls that need it.